# A Simple Wpf MVVM Binding Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying my hands on WPF MVVM. I have written following code in XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Accounting.Menu"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"  
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Accounting"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="105" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:MenuViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
       <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MenuHeader}"/>
       </StackPanel>
       <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItems}" Height="70"/>             
    </StackPanel>     
</UserControl>
```

I have got a `MenuViewModel` with properties `MenuHeader` and `MenuItems`. I get values in both the properties during runtime. Former is bound to text of `TextBlock` and latter to ItemSource of `ListBox`. But when I run the solution, TextBlock and ListBox are empty.

**Edit: Code of ViewModel**

```
  public class MenuViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
        AccountingDataClassesDataContext db;

        private string _menuType;
        public string MenuHeader { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> MenuItems { get; set; }

        public MenuViewModel()
        { 

        }

        public MenuViewModel(string menuType)
        {
            this._menuType = menuType;
            db = new AccountingDataClassesDataContext();
            if (menuType == "Vouchers")
            {
                var items = db.Vouchers.OrderBy(t => t.VoucherName).Select(v => v.VoucherName).ToList<string>();

                if (items.Any())
                {
                    MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<string>(items);
                    MenuHeader = "Vouchers";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Menu not found");
            }

        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your view model?

Comment: Post the code of your ViewModel

Comment: Have you set the data context of your view to be the required viewmodel?

Comment: @DarrenYoung: Yes, Menu (View) requires datacontext MenuViewModel

Comment: @ChrisF: INotifyPropertyChanged is not an issue. Is it something relating to Binding of Ancestor or relative binding ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating your ViewModel in the XAML using your ViewModel's default contructor which does nothing. All your population code is in the non-default contructor which is never called.

The more usual way is to create the ViewModel in code, and inject it into the view either explicitly using `View.DataContext = ViewModel`, or impllcitly using a DataTemplate.

Comment: I agree, I dont need default constructor, but when I assign datacontext from xaml, compiler says `there is no default constructor`. I will try injecting viewmodel and removing default constructor.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, I removed datacontext assignment from XAML and the default constructor, and it work like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to trigger the OnPropertyChanged event. I am not sure if you are using a MVVM library (since you inherit from ViewModelBase you might be using MVVM Light for example), there they wrap the OnPropertyChanged in the RaisePropertyChanged event handler.
Triggering the event will inform WPF to update the UI.

```
string m_MenuHeader;
public string MenuHeader 
{ 
    get
    {
        return m_MenuHeader;
    } 
    set
    {
        m_MenuHeader=value; OnPropertyChanged("MenuHeader");
    }
}
```